# How to dynamically add a UserControl in MVVM pattern?

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

This is a sample source to help explain my explanation

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PaggingButtonList}">            
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <UserControl Name="{Binding ViewName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I want to dynamically add  as in the code above. Unfortunately, the only way to add a View I know is to . So I want to know what to assign to what? Section in  to dynamically find and add View file of my project. Thank you

[image]

Comment: What I want to know is how to bind MyView.xaml in my Project View folder to <UserControl> above. The link you provided is not listed on this question.

Comment: show us your VIewList

Comment: How to add a property to the View List The question is whether you can add a View in the actual UI by adding code in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `ContentControl` to host your `UserControl`:

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding Name,Converter={StaticResource NameToContentConverter}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Define ObservableCollection:

```
public ObservableCollection<object> ViewList { get; set; } = 
  new ObservableCollection<object>();
```

and to add Content later

```
ViewList.Add(new View() { Name = "yourUserControlName" });
```

Your `View` Class:

```
public class View
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Since ContentControl.Content  expect object and you are passing it as a `string`
you can use Converter.

**Converter:**

```
public class NameToContentConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value != null)
        {
            Type userControl =  Type.GetType(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name +"."+ value,null,null);
            return Activator.CreateInstance(userControl);
        }
        return "";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

to know more about Activator see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx)

**[image: Output:]**